# compute matrix product for multiple inputs

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am trying to compute a transform given by b = A*x. A is a (3,4) matrix. If x is one (4,1) vector the result is b (3,1).

Instead, for x I have a bunch of vectors concatenated into a matrix and I am trying to evaluate the transform for each value of x. So x is (20, 4). How do I broadcast this in numpy such that I get 20 resulting values for b (20,3)?

I could loop over each input and compute the output but it feels like there must be a better way using broadcasting.

Eg.

```
A = [[1,0,0,0],
[2,0,0,0],
[3,0,0,0]]
```

if x is:

```
x = [[1,1,1,1],
[2,2,2,2]]

b = [[1,2,3],
[2,4,6]]
```

Each row of x is multiplied with A and result is stored as a row in b.

Comment: "for x I have a bunch of vectors concatenated into a matrix and I am trying to evaluate the transform for each value of x. So x is (20, 4)." <- Can you elaborate more on this and give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numpy dot

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.normal(size=(3,4))

x = np.random.normal(size=(4,20))

y = np.dot(A,x)

print y.shape
```

Result: (3, 20)

And of course if you want (20,3) you can use np.transpose()